# Ruby Selenium Webdriver - Wont click?

Tags: ruby, selenium

Just starting out with ruby + webdriver, I've made a small script and I am wondering why the script wont click on the web element and then input the value?

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'selenium-webdriver'

class Standard_webdriver_ruby
  driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
  driver.get 'http://demoqa.com/contact/'
  driver.manage.window.maximize
  wait = Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new(:timeout => 5)

  fillFormData = Array.new('rob', 'rob@hotmail.co.uk', 'whoop', 'Message content')

  name_field = driver.find_element :css => ('#wpcf7-f375-p28-o1 > form > p:nth-child(2) > span > input')
  name_field.click
  name_field.send_keys(fillFormData[0])
  email_field = driver.find_element :css =>  '#wpcf7-f375-p28-o1 > form > p:nth-child(3) > span > input'
  email_field.click
  email_field.send_keys(fillFormData[1])
  subject_field = driver.find_element :css => '#wpcf7-f375-p28-o1 > form > p:nth-child(4) > span > input'
  subject_field.click
  subject_field.send_keys(fillFormData[2])
  message_field = driver.find_element :css => '#wpcf7-f375-p28-o1 > form > p:nth-child(5) > span > textarea'
  message_field.click
  message_field.send_keys(fillFormData[3])
end
```

Comment: and whats the error you are getting?

Comment: in `initialize': wrong number of arguments (4 for 0..2) (ArgumentError) do I need to add it into a def initialize block? @VigneshParamasivam

Comment: initializing the array is incorrect. read ruby http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are instantiating the array erroneously:

```
# incorrect
fillFormData = Array.new('rob', 'rob@hotmail.co.uk', 'whoop', 'Message content')

# correct
fillFormData = ['rob', 'rob@hotmail.co.uk', 'whoop', 'Message content']

# correct, ruby-way
fillFormData = %w[rob rob@hotmail.co.uk whoop Message\ content]
```

[`Array#new`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-c-new) expects size or an array as an argument.